# Objects gets destroyed before the scope

Tags: visual-studio, c++17, c++14

I have tried experimenting with normal class , object with vector tried a simple data entry , but the object is getting closed once the data entered , i have no clue on this please assist.

I Have added some debugging couts in destructor and constructor for checking them how it works.

Entis.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>


class Entis {
    int ntis = 0;;
    std::string name;

public:
    Entis(); 
    ~Entis();
    void displayEntis();
    int get_Entis();
    std::string get_name();
    void set_Entis(int ntis);
    void set_name(std::string name);

};
```

Entis.cpp

```
#include "Entis.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::string;
using std::endl;

Entis::Entis() {  cout << "Created Entis object" << endl; }
Entis::~Entis() { cout << "destroyed Entis object" << endl; }

void Entis::displayEntis() {

    cout << "Name  : " << name << endl;
    cout << "Entis : " << ntis << endl;

}

int Entis::get_Entis() {

    return ntis;
}

string Entis::get_name() {

    return name;
}

void Entis::set_Entis(int num) {
    ntis = num;
}

void Entis::set_name(string entis_name) {
    name = entis_name;
}
```

learning.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::string;
using std::vector;
using std::endl;
#include"Entis.h"

int main()
{
    
    int n = 0;
    cout << "-----Entis List-----" << endl;
    cout << "enter the number of Entis people" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    vector <Entis> v(n);
    cout << "Please enter the the Entis details as follows..." << endl;
    for (Entis obj : v) {
        cout << "Enter name : ";
        string name;
        cin >> name;
        cout << "Enter Entis no : ";
        int numb;
        cin >> numb;
        obj.set_Entis(numb);
        obj.set_name(name);
    }

    cout << "Printing all Entis" << endl;

    for (Entis obj : v) {
        obj.displayEntis();
    }
    

    std::cin.get();
}
```

Output :

```
-----Entis List-----
enter the number of Entis people
2
Created Entis object
Created Entis object
Please enter the the Entis details as follows...
Enter name : tarun
Enter Entis no : 27
destroyed Entis object
Enter name : lisa
Enter Entis no : 27
destroyed Entis object
Printing all Entis
Name  :
Entis : 0
destroyed Entis object
Name  :
Entis : 0
destroyed Entis object
destroyed Entis object
destroyed Entis object
```

Thank you so much!!

Comment: I have made the code working with changing the loop with     
`for (int i = 0; i<v.size(); i++){

        cout << "Enter name : ";
        string name;
        cin >> name;
        cout << "Enter Entis no : ";
        int ntis;
        cin >> ntis;
        v[i].set_Entis(ntis);
        v[i].set_name(name);
    }`
But still I cant understand why the old above code is not working as expected

Answer (score 0):

You create a copy of the object in the loop.

Try this instead:

```
for (Entis const& obj : v)
```

Comment: "C++ the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function            object type is: const Entis" im getting the above error for those two member functions

Comment: Maybe remove the const but keep the `&`